# Installing JDK 8 after removing OpenJDK 7

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

I just removed OpenJDK at Ubuntu Software Center, and downloaded JDK 8 at official Oracle site, and installed with alien.
But when I type `java -version` at terminal, it keeps returning

```
root@pcowner:/home/owner/Downloads# java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

So I rechecked Ubuntu software center, and saw OpenJDK is not installed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to install the Oracle Java 8 JDK through the [webupd8 ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html), it usually does all the "dirty" work for you (download java when updates available, install them, and run update-alternatives to make oracle jdk the default one).